# How to format string to mm/dd/yyyy with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have been struggling with this particular regular expression and was wondering if anyone can help. I have an input field that allows users to enter text and if a user enters 01201990 I have a method that converts it to 01/20/19/90 The problem is I don't want the regular expression to **continue** after the *mm/dd/* my end result would look like this **01/20/1990** Any help would be amazing.

```
    var tmparray = [];
      tmparray.push(
      tmp.model
        // here is where I dont know how to prevent the regex
        // from continuing after 01/20/
        .match(new RegExp('.{1,2}', 'g'))
        .join("/")
    );

    tmp.model = tmparray;
    console.log(tmp.model);
```

Comment: Do you have to go for REGEX?

Comment: Tried `input type="date"` ?

Comment: are you using jquery or any other Library? They have thing built in for such scenarios

Comment: What if I would type `02292015`, `12345678`, `09312015`

Comment: Besides `type=date` wont work for old browsers

Comment: If you are using jquery you dont have to type.. It's a date picker widget that pops up.. Have a look at http:// www.jqueryui.com/datepicker

Comment: The type date wouldn't work as it adds a component and I am simply doing this to format the input val as users type I have a separate method for validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **[`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)** in this case

```js
document.write('19101992'.replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/, '$1/$2/$3'))
```

Your code will be like

```
var tmparray = [];
  tmparray.push(
  tmp.model
    // here is where I dont know how to prevent the regex
    // from continuing after 01/20/
    .replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/g, '$1/$2/$3')
);

tmp.model = tmparray;
console.log(tmp.model);
```

Answer (score 1):

why not just match on:
/(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})/

then dd/mm/yyyy is:
$1/$2/$3

(I can't see why you'd match {1,2} since you can't tell the difference between 1/11/1990 and 11/1/1990 and in either case would get 11/11/990...)

Comment: Could you please format your answer though. I see your answer is relevant. It would be useful for people who come accross such problems

Answer (score 0):

Try using `String.prototype.slice()` , `String.prototype.concat()`

```js
var str = "01201990" , d = "/"
, res = str.slice(0,2).concat(d + str.slice(2,4)).concat(d + str.slice(4));
console.log(res)
```

Comment: This would fail if a smart user tries to punch in date as 1/12/1991 instead of 01/12/1991

Comment: @AkshayKhandelwal _"This would fail if a smart user tries to punch in date as 1/12/1991 instead of 01/12/1991"_ ? See OP at _" have an input field that allows users to enter text and if a user enters 01201990"_ Eight characters appear required ?

Comment: I dont think so. No one is going to validate number of characters except in case where absolutely necessary such as phone numbers. To me a REGEX should be a Valid answer. Not that your code won't work for given scenario but REGEX would be the optimal choice

Answer (score 0):

use regex [0-9]{2}(?=(?:[0-9]{4})). for more information please check link https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/regular-expressions-cookbook/9781449327453/ch06s12.html